# How could a group be a manifold?

Tags: group-theory, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

For example a [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) is defined as a certain differentiable manifold, but what does this mean geometrically, and what is gained by viewing something abstract and algebraic as a manifold?

First, I know there are severel quite abstract definitions of a manifold, but what I know from my analysis courses, a manifold is something that could be defined by equations (i.e. something like $f^{-1}(0)$ for a regular function) or for example as defined in *Munkres: Analysis on Manifolds*, p. 109:

> A subseteq M of $\mathbb R^n$ is called a **$k$-dimensional manifold** (in $\mathbb R^n)$ if for every point $x \in M$ the following condition is satisfied:
>
> (M) There is an open set $U$ containing $x$, an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and a diffeomorphism $h : U \to V$ such that
>   $$
>  h(U\cap M) = V \cap (\mathbb R^k \times \{0\}) 
>   = \{ y \in V : y^{k+1} = \ldots = y^n = 0 \}.
> $$

So a manifold is something concrete, something that I can think of sitting in $\mathbb R^n$ (I know vaguely there are some intrinsic definitions saying something like a set $X$ is manifold if it has a topology and to each point there exists a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^n$).

So I am used to think of a manifold as a geomtric object, and in some sense this are the explanations I find everywhere, but in what sense could a group be something "geometrically concrete", for example $SL(n, K)$ is also a manifold (this could be seen by noting that it is the inverse image $\det^{-1}(1)$), but again what does this mean geometrically and what is gained by seeing for example $SL(n,K)$ as a manifold?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is geometric and addition makes it into a group. Addition can be seen geometrically as translation. Likewise $\mathbb{R}^+$ with multiplication, of $\mathbb{C}$ with addition, or $\mathbb{C}^*$ with multiplication.

Comment: Already in $\mathbb{C}$ you probably know many examples of algebraic problems that are easier to solve by interpreting them geometrically.

Comment: Yes, this is all clear to me, but how to think of $SL(n, K)$ or a lie group geometrically, what picture should I have in mind?

Comment: Picture? For a high dimensional object? I don't know. [A blurry transparent blob](https://youtu.be/-x4P65EKjt0?t=1m48s)? Pictures as less useful than the properties (differential, topological).

Comment: Manifolds are spaces that are locally parameterized by tuples of real numbers. That fits $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ perfectly: use the coordinates of the matrix as parameters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll address two points here:

- how can a group be a geometric object, and
- what is gained by the geometric viewpoint

Let's start with an easy example.  Consider $SO_2$, the group of rotations in $\Bbb R^2$.  We can identify this group with the set $S_1 = \{z \in \Bbb C: |z| = 1\}$.  Geometrically, this set is a circle in $\Bbb C$ (which, geometrically, is just $\Bbb R^2$).  The idea encapsulated here is that we associate every point on the circle with a rotation by the corresponding angle.

The geometry adds a *differential topology* to the group, so that we can now take limits and derivatives in our group.  So, for example, if we have a sequence $(A_n) \subset SO_2$ with $A_n \to A$, then if $A$ acts on $\Bbb R^2$, we'll have $A_n x \to Ax$ for any $x \in \Bbb R^2$.  We can also make sense of a derivative: take 
$$
A(t) = e^{iat}, \quad a \in \Bbb R 
$$
then we have
$$
A'(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{iat} - 1}{t} = ia
$$
So that $ia \in i\Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$ is an element of the tangent space of this group at the identity.

---

By far, the most useful thing that comes out of manifold structure to the group is the notion of a *tangent space*.  In particular, we define the *tangent space at the identity* in a Lie Group $G$ by
$$
g = T_I(G) = \{A'(0): A:[-1,1] \to G \text{ is differentiable with } A(0) = I\}
$$
This gives us the *Lie algebra* associated with $G$.  The Lie algebra $g$ is a vector space with a natural operation given by "Lie brackets", defined by 
$$
[X,Y] = XY - YX \quad X,Y \in g
$$
It turns out that Lie groups can (often) be completely understood in terms of their Lie algebras, which are (perhaps surprisingly) often easier to work with.

---

### Tangent space of $SL_n$:

Define the matrix exponential by
$$
\exp[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X^k
$$
where we define $X^0 = I$.  Consider $SL_n$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

For any matrix $X$, we can consider the map $A:[-1,1] \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ defined by
$$
A(t) = \exp[tX]
$$
And we have $A'(t) = Xe^{tX}$, so that $A'(0) = X$.

We note that for any matrix $M$, $\det(\exp[M]) = \exp[\operatorname{trace}(M)]$.  It follows that $A(t)$ will only be a path in $SL_n$ if $X$ has trace $0$.

So, the tangent space of $SL_n$ will include all trace-zero matrices.  In fact, there's a theorem that allows us to state that this is the *entire* tangent space to $SL_n$, so that the trace zero matrices form the Lie algebra of $SL_n$.

Comment: The identity is no rotation, this corresponds to the point $(1,0)$ on the circle, In your example the tangent space are all vectors $i\cdot a$ for $a \in \mathbb R$, so this seems to coincide with $\mbox{span}\{(0,1)^T\}$, so it is indeed the tangent space in $(1,0)$ at the circle. But for your abstract definition of tangent space at zero, what are the maps $A : [-1,1] \to G$ in general, some arbitray differentiable map, so the tangent space are the derivatives of all differentiable maps mapping the identity to the identity... this seems kinda abstract to me, is there a more intuitve def...

Comment: The best way to see what going on here is to see what it looks like for matrices.  I can do another example with $SL_n$, if you'd like (if/when I have time)

Comment: In your example the maps $A$ have a concrete interpretation, but in general what is the interpretation of these maps, maybe another example would be nice if you have time...

Comment: In general, the maps $A$ are going to be paths on the manifold that pass through the point corresponding to the group identity.

Comment: @Stefan the intuitive definition is that tangent vectors at the identity are infinitesimally small perturbations of the identity *map* on your group. Then the Lie bracket is the commutator of these tiny maps.