# An example of a group with a topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

Do you know an example of a group with a topology satisfying both the following two conditions

1. the product is *separately continuous* but not *jointly continuous*
2. the inversion map *is continuous*.

Comment: One important example of a group with a topology is a Lie Group.  With that in mind, you might find [this post to be interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258101/81360).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take, for instance, $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, endowed with the Zariski topology (that is, a non-empty set $A$ is open if and only if $A^\complement$ is finite). Then the inversion ($x\mapsto-x$) is clearly continuous and addition is clearly separately continuous. But it is *not* jointly continuous since, for instance $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2\,|\,x+y=0\}$ is not a closed set.

Answer (score 7):

Let $G$ be any infinite group and give it the cofinite topology.  Then the product is separately continuous as is inversion, since any bijection $G\to G$ is continuous.  But the product is not jointly continuous, since $\{1\}$ is closed but its preimage is not.  (Or, you can just cite the fact that any $T_0$ topological group is Hausdorff, so $G$ cannot be a topological group.)